# MySQL: Use function with parameter inside of view

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use a function with a parameter in a view. The parameter is from the select of each row. To explain my question have a look on the following simplified example:

```
my_function(id int):
    SET r = (select exists(select ... where key = id));
    return r;


my_view:
    select table.key as key, table.date as date, ...
    my_function(key) as fct_value
    FROM table
```

Or are there any other ways to use the exists-Statement with a dynamic key (each row) directly in the view without additional functions?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.  I am pretty sure that a function is not needed.

Comment: I'am just asking if such a call with the selected key as parameter for each row is possible in a view. If not, I'll open another detailed question. But for now, this is the only possibility to archieve my desired view.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I suggested this tactic in a [recent answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41163031/1695906).